# No laravel sync folders in homestead vagrant on windows

Tags: bash, laravel, vagrant, virtual-machine, homestead

i installed vagrant lately on my windows 7 machine, i successfully runned the virtual machine because i can ssh to it but no synchronization between my local project and the homestead.

my yaml file is like :

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/User/Homestead/projects
      to: /home/vagrant/sites

sites:
    - map: laravel.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/laravel/public
      hhvm: true

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

My laravel project is inside projects folder in my local homestead directory, but it seems that the sites folder that links to it is not synced with it !!

i'm not good at unix command line but is it weird that ls -la command work but ls alone don't seem to work as i saw if tutorials ?

[image]

### update :

After changing the hosts file setup for : `127.0.0.1 laravel.dev` to `192.168.10.10 laravel.dev` the site was accessible in my browser, but the problem of no syncronization still happening (i had to install a new laravel in vangrant) i want to deplay my project from wamp to projects folder and be syncronized with "sites" in homestead

Comment: `ls --help | grep -w "\-a"` returns: `-a, --all do not ignore entries starting with .`

Comment: i just did it but the "sites" folder wasn't there, it should be there as mentioned in the yaml file

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "ls -la command work but ls alone don't seem to work". How did `ls -la` work? You only showed us `ls -a`, and clearly there's no `sites`.

Comment: I think you need to mention the full path for the folders, either use `C:/Users/User/Homestead/projects` or simply `~/Homestead/Projects`.

Comment: @4ae1e1 both `ls -a` and `ls -la` worked with same results (no sites directory), what i meant is that in tutorials people do `ls`command and they get current folders and files but for me it just do nothing.
@Mahozi i tried with both paths  still no "sites" directory

Comment: i just succesfully installed a fresh new laravel on unix and run it on vagrant the problem was the ip in hosts, it should be 192.168.10.10 not 127.0.0.1.
but i still have the problem of files are not synchronized between the host folder "projects" and the guest folder "sites"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your Homestead.yaml
In the line

```
---

 folders:
   - map: E:/projects //your projects folder here
    to: /home/vagrant/Code

 sites:
   - map: homestead.app
   to: /home/vagrant/Code/Laravel/public
```

Now if you are using Windows, open notepad as administrator and your hosts

```
  System32/drivers/etc/hosts


  192.168.10.10 laravel5angularapp.dev
  192.168.10.10 angular2laravel.dev
  192.168.10.10 laravel5-angular2.dev
  192.168.10.10 yourproject.dev
```

Now access your homestead

```
 homestead up
 homestead ssh
```

Inside homestead

```
 cd Code
 ls -a
```

All your projects should appear here, then

```
cd ~
```

then

```
serve yourproject.dev /home/vagrant/Code/yourlaravelprojectname/public/
```

Then

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

Or

```
homestead reload
```

Your project should be running in

```
http://yourproject.dev
```

Comment: i have put laravel folder in "projects" folder like so "/home/vagrant/sites/projects/laravel"

Answer (score 2):

I've tried many things but none of them worked. Finally i've changed map folder to the full path version and then run the vagrant reload command and it was ok.

Homestead.yaml

```
folders:
- map: C:/Users/username/Code
  to: /home/vagrant/Code.
```

`vagrant reload`

Comment: You can use relative paths to the vagrant folder as @mahozi saids: `./Code` but you need to execute `vagrant reload` after changing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `~/Homestead/projects` in windows is the same the C:\Users\your_user\your_folders